# A royal affix riddle

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix is a key member in rock history
> My infix is a deadly sin missing its tail
> My suffix is a prefix for the persistent
> **What am I?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

> **SIRE** - a term of address for a master or ruler (hence the use of 'royal' in the title).

*My prefix is a key member in rock history*

> **Si** is the chemical symbol for **Silicon**, a key component of [*rocks* and minerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicate_mineral) that make up 90% of the Earth's crust.

*My infix is a deadly sin missing its tail*

> **IR** is the *deadly sin* 'IRE' (also known as wrath or anger) without the final 'E'.

*My suffix is a prefix for the persistent*

> **RE** is a common prefix for verbs implying something has been done again (and again and again...), like 'repeat', 'rerun', 'redo', etc. (And if somebody does something repeatedly they could be described as *persistent* in their task...)